# How to push updates to EnvoyProxy dynamic configuration using control plane?

Tags: go, envoyproxy

I'm trying to write a control plane which can dynamically update many Envoy instances. From what I can tell, the easiest way to do this is by using Envoy's dynamic resources. The problem I'm encountering is how to push the updates. Because I have very many different Envoy instances, and I'm expecting that each update should be pretty small, I want to use the incremental xDS with Delta Discovery Request in the control plane. However, I'm confused how Envoy subscribes to the control plane and how to push small updates to Envoy in Go.

I've looked into trying to use ADS or other methods but they seem much less efficient.